# Activity after deep linking a chat in teams

Tags: .net-core, microsoft-teams

I have a .Net Core application from where I have deep linked a particular chatbot of Microsoft Teams. It is an Azure Bot. It is properly opening the chat in Teams, which is a one-time process. However, as soon as the chat opens I want to catch a bot activity, which I'm unable to do. I want to send a welcome message as soon as the chat opens.

Please suggest which activity I can catch after deep linking or what other approaches I can take to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @Raj, Can you share the deeplink format or document you are referring to redirect to your bot.

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT
Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links)

Comment: Hi @Raj, The even can only be initiated when you install your bot or send some message. Deeplinking will not invoke any handler.

Answer (score 1):

You want to listen for the `conversationUpdate` event in your bot code. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet). Specifically for Teams, can use the ["Team Members Added"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#team-members-added) event.

Remember that Teams bots are built on top of the generalised Microsoft Bot Framework, so if you want some more background on Welcome Messages, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: My bot has already been added to my Teams, hence the method `OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync` is not getting invoked. I tried to remove the bot but it's showing only 'Hide' and 'Block' options. Can you tell me how I can remove/uninstall the Azure bot completely from my Teams?

Comment: I was creating an Azure Bot. That was not triggering for any of the events. I finally created a Teams Application via Teams' App Studio and used its bot instead, which is working properly afterward.